# Prove $x^3+y^3+z^3\geq 3xyz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that, $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}_+\cup \{0\}$,
$$x^3+y^3+z^3\geq 3xyz\text{.}$$

---

I've been trying for a while now whithout making any significant progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)$

Clearly the first factor is $\geq 0$. The second factor can be written as $$\frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{2}$$ which is $\geq 0$

Answer (score 4):

The [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) gives that

$$\frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{x^3y^3z^3} \implies x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \ge 3xyz \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$x\mapsto \ln(x) \; $ is concave at $ (0,+\infty) \;$ since its second derivative $\; x \mapsto \frac{-1}{x^2}\; $  is negative.

$$\frac 13 + \frac 13 + \frac 13 = 1$$
thus

$$\ln\Bigl(\frac 13(x^3+y^3+z^3)\Bigr)\ge$$
$$ \frac 13\Bigl(\ln(x^3)+\ln(y^3)+\ln(z^3)\Bigr)$$
$$(=\ln(xyz))$$